# VB check value of structure

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, data-structures

I have two structures that sometimes one gets filled with data from a user or sometimes both. I need to check either the whole structure to see if it has had data input or not. I'd also be ok if I can even check just a variable to see if it is not empty or null (which is what I have done below). When the code runs the btnTurn.Enabled is always disabled whether the structure has data or not. Could this be a problem with my boolean?

Structures

```
 Public Structure StructSurvData
            Friend szTBMNum As String
            Friend dblTBMElev1 As Double
            Friend dblTBMElev2 As Double
            Friend dblTBMElev3 As Double
            Friend dblBACKSIGHT1 As Double
            Friend dblBACKSIGHT2 As Double
            Friend dblBACKSIGHT3 As Double
            Friend dblFORESIGHT1 As Double
            Friend dblFORESIGHT2 As Double
            Friend dblFORESIGHT3 As Double
            Friend szNewMPEDescr As String
            Friend szDataComm As String

        End Structure

        Public Structure StructSurvData2
            Friend szTBMNum2 As String
            Friend dblTBMElev4 As Double
            Friend dblTBMElev5 As Double
            Friend dblTBMElev6 As Double
            Friend dblBACKSIGHT4 As Double
            Friend dblBACKSIGHT5 As Double
            Friend dblBACKSIGHT6 As Double
            Friend dblFORESIGHT4 As Double
            Friend dblFORESIGHT5 As Double
            Friend dblFORESIGHT6 As Double
            Friend szNewMPEDescr2 As String
            Friend szDataComm2 As String
        End Structure
```

If/else

```
 If structSD2.szTBMNum2 = Nothing Then
                btnTurn.Enabled = False
            ElseIf structSD2.szTBMNum2 <> Nothing Then
                btnTurn.Enabled = True
            End If
```

Comment: For strings, you should use one of [it's function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) to detect null or empty. It all depends on what you mean by "has values". The best way would be to have a function that returns true or false.

Comment: Side note: are you sure those should be defined as structures?  They are pretty large. Using a normal class is probably better here.  And your use of `friend` is also suspect.

Comment: @sstan This code is for an application that was built years ago. Trust me I don't want to use a structure but its easier without having to do a lot of re-coding for the changes that the customer wants, that has nothing to do with how the data is stored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always use `is nothing` instead of `=nothing` and `isnot nothing` instead of `<> nothing`

```
        If structSD2.szTBMNum2 is Nothing Then
            btnTurn.Enabled = False
        ElseIf structSD2.szTBMNum2 isnot Nothing Then
            btnTurn.Enabled = True
        End If
```

Or even better as @zaggler recommended:

```
        btnTurn.Enabled = structSD2.szTBMNum2 Is Nothing
```

Comment: `btnTurn.Enabled = structSD2.szTBMNum2 Is Nothing` just a little easier on thee eyes...

Comment: Yeah, don’t write such code — it’s an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yeah, agreed - it's just easier for the OP to see the change this way.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `it's an anti-pattern`, I understand what this means. Could you clarify more of why the statement would be an issue... Is it because it could be a maintenance issue, similar code somewhere else etc...

Comment: @Zaggler Because it’s code bloat: It is five times longer than the statement you suggested, and provides no benefit to offset this, either in readability or performance. And as such it negatively impacts the readability of the code because it detracts attention away from the essential.

Comment: @KonradRudolph are you talking about the accepted solution or my comment?

Comment: @Zaggler I was agreeing with you, that the code suggested in your comment is superior.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I was confused, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

```
If structSD2.szTBMNNum Is Nothing Then
```